# Delete item from list in Python while iterating over it

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a round robin algorithm for a tournament app.

When the number of players is odd, I add `'DELETE'` to the list of players, but later, when I want to delete all items from schedule list that contain `'DELETE'`, I can't -- one is always left. Please take a look at the code -- the problem is simple and I suppose it's about lists; I just i can't see it.

```
"""
Round-robin tournament:
1, 2, 3, 4, | 5, 6, 7, 8    =>  1, 2, 3, 4  => rotate all but 1 =>  1, 5, 2, 3  => repeat =>    1, 6, 5, 2  ...
                    5, 6, 7, 8              6, 7, 8, 4          7, 8, 4, 3
in every round pick l1[0] and l2[0] as first couple, after that l1[1] and l2[1]...
"""

import math

lst = []
schedule = []
delLater = False

for i in range(3):                  #make list of numbers
    lst.append(i+1)

if len(lst) % 2 != 0:               #if num of items is odd, add 'DELETE'
    lst.append('DELETE')
    delLater = True


while len(schedule) < math.factorial(len(lst))/(2*math.factorial(len(lst) - 2)): #!(n)/!(n-k)

    mid = len(lst)/2

    l1 = lst[:mid]
    l2 = lst[mid:]

    for i in range(len(l1)):            
        schedule.append((l1[i], l2[i]))         #add lst items in schedule

    l1.insert(1, l2[0])             #rotate lst
    l2.append(l1[-1])
    lst = l1[:-1] + l2[1:]


if delLater == True:                #PROBLEM!!! One DELETE always left in list
    for x in schedule:
        if 'DELETE' in x:
            schedule.remove(x)

i = 1
for x in schedule:
    print i, x
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the list while iterating over it:

```
for x in schedule:
    if 'DELETE' in x:
        schedule.remove(x)
```

Instead, try:

```
schedule[:] = [x for x in schedule if 'DELETE' not in x]
```

For more info, see [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Comment: There was no need to copy the in-place assignment from the other answers, it's not better.

Comment: thanks for the answer and info. to be honest i still don't know how to ask question about python properly or where to look for the answer. i didn't know that removing items during iteration is different.

Comment: @Rodic: My pleasure. This problem is something every Python coder runs into sooner or later.

Comment: @agf: if not using `[:]` creates bugs, then using it *is* better.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 7):

```
schedule[:] = [x for x in schedule if 'DELETE' not in x]
```

See the other questions about [deleting from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500888/removing-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it).

Comment: +1 for using [:] to just modify the same list object.

Comment: Why use in-place assignment? @Macke there is likely no benefit to it. It briefly saves a bit of memory, and it's a bit slower. Most likely neither matters.

Comment: @agf: Just to fix the existing code with as little change as possible. Personally, I'd just use generators everywhere or write a algorithm that doesn't need the bogus entries, but that's not the question.

Comment: @agf Readability. Introducing another list object introduces another variable to remember when reading the code.

Comment: @Velociraptors What does object identity matter? You can still use the same name, you don't need a new variable: `schedule = [x for x in schedule if 'DELETE' not in x]`

Comment: @agf: use in-place assignment when it's important to keep all the names bound to the list synchronized.

Answer (score 4):

To remove elements from a list while iterating over it, you need to go backwards:

```
if delLater == True:
    for x in schedule[-1::-1]):
        if 'DELETE' in x:
            schedule.remove(x)
```

A better option is to use a list-comprehension:

```
schedule[:] = [item for item in schedule if item != 'DELETE']
```

Now, you could just do `schedule =` instead of `schedule[:] =` -- what's the difference?  One example is this:

```
schedule = [some list stuff here]  # first time creating
modify_schedule(schedule, new_players='...') # does validation, etc.

def modify_schedule(sched, new_players):
    # validate, validate, hallucinate, illustrate...
    sched = [changes here]
```

At this point, all the changes that `modify_schedule` made have been lost.  Why?  Because instead of modifying the list object in place, it re-bound the name `sched` to a new list, leaving the original list still bound to the name `schedule` in the caller.

So whether or not you use `list_object[:] =` depends on if you want any other names bound to your list to see the changes.

Comment: In a correct design, `def` returns `sched` which is assigned back to `schedule`, or in a considered-bad-form-but-logical design, you don't pass the schedule and you use `global schedule`. The example design you have above is simply wrong, whether or not you use in-place assignment, because it isn't clear that `sched` and `schedule` refer to the same thing at the point where you're changing `schedule`.

Comment: Also, did you try your loop version? I'm not sure how it's supposed to work, but it's got at least a couple of errors. You're trying to remove something that you don't know is in the list (the index from `enumerate`) and your values for slicing don't appear to make sense.

Comment: That is not the correct way to use slices to reverse a list, try `schedule[-1::-1]`, or better yet `reversed(schedule)`, since the slice will construct a new list anyway.

Comment: @F.J something like `for _ in range(sum('DELETE' in x for x in schedule)): schedule.remove(x)` works just as well -- since `remove` does a search anyway, you're really just using the _number of matches_ not their location, so just de-sychronize the two operations and there is no need to act in reverse, even if you want to use a loop.

Comment: @agf: No, unfortunately -- my main point was refuting your claim that `[:]` was unnecessary and a waste of time.  Loop version fixed, thanks.

Comment: @agf: so change the call site to `schedule[:] = modify_schedule(schedule, ...)` -- my point still stands about multiple names being bound to the one list object, and the decision about keeping them in sync (or not).

Comment: code works just fine with schedule[:] = [x for x in schedule if 'DELETE' not in x]. im new at python and programming in general so  there are mistakes, wish i know more so i can discuss about them. thanks to all for help.

Comment: agree with @AndrewClark , schedule[-1::-1] same as schedule[:] constructs a copy.

Comment: @iperov: Then you missed the point twice: 1) `schedule[-1::-1]` makes a reverse copy, while `schedule[:]` makes a normal copy; 2) my answer addresses the question of why you would want to assign using `schedule[:] = ...` instead of `schedule = ...` .

Answer (score 2):

Don't modify a sequence being iterated over.

```
schedule[:] = [x for x in schedule if 'DELETE' not in x]
```