# Deleting list elements whilst iterating over it

Tags: python

I need to delete elements from a list whilst iterating over it (I cannot create a new list as it is referenced in code I have no control over).

The best I've come up with is:

```
last_index = len(somelist) - 1
for (index,item) in enumerate(reversed(somelist)):
    if somecondition(item):
        del somelist[last_index - index]
```

Are there better alternatives? I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573115/delete-item-from-list-in-python-while-iterating-over-it) too, but none of the solutions provided are as efficient or as concise (IMHO).

Comment: How much more concise and efficient would you like? [Alex Martelli's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1208792/78845) appears to be both. Questions relating to opinions are not a good match for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure your code actually works?  initializing `somelist` to `range(100)` and `somecondition(item)` to `item % 2`, I end up with an IndexError.

Comment: @mgilson my first thought was that it should be `del somelist[-index]` (with `enumerate(...,start=1)`) otherwise, all ways I can think of are already covered by the previous post

Comment: @isedev i'm not sure regarding to efficiency but also you can do somelist.remove(item) instead of reversing and enumerating.

Comment: @JonClements -- It's a shame this is a dupe -- I might have eventually gotten a `great answer` badge for it :O)

Comment: sorry, cut'n'paste error in above code. Edited now.

Comment: @Johnsyweb -- having a bad day, hadn't seen the question with the answer you were referring to (there's another with nearly same title - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list)). Indeed, Alex's answer is what I was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension + slice assignment, which is certainly more concise -- I don't know about efficiency (although I would expect it to do better in that regard as well since you don't need to keep shifting elements in the list over every time you delete an item ...)

```
somelist[:] = [ x for x in somelist if not somecondition(x) ]
```

Comment: That's about 45% faster. Thanks.