# I'm trying to learn why I can't seem to delete every index in a list with a loop

Tags: python, list

I'm not sure why my list is not deleting every char that is indexed based on a second List. Below is the code:

```
L1 = ['e', 'i', 'l', 'n', 's', 't']
L2 = ['e', 'i', 'l', 'n', 's', 't']

for n_item in range(len(L1)):
    if L1[n_item] in L2:
     del L2[n_item]
```

Below is the error that I'm getting:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#241>", line 3, in <module>
 del L2[n_item]
 IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Thanks for any help ....

Comment: also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573115/delete-item-from-list-in-python-while-iterating-over-it?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you remove the earlier items, the list becomes shorter, so the later indicies don't exist. This is a symptom of iterating by index in Python - which is a terrible idea. It's not how Python is designed and will generally make unreadable, slow, inflexible code.

Instead, use a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to construct a new list:

```
[item for item in L1 if item not in L2]
```

Note that if `L2` is large, it might be worth making it a set first, as membership tests on a set are much quicker.

Comment: And, if necessary, you can also replace the old list with the new one in place:  `L2[:] = [ ... ]`.  This keeps things consistent with what OP is trying to do, but also removes the penalty of shifting the elements after each `del`.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you delete an element at an index, the list is changed.

```
>>> items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> len(items)
4
>>> items[1]
'b'
>>> del items[1]
>>> items[1]
'c'
>>> len(items)
3
```

whats causing your error is that the `len` of the list is changed when you delete the item, however, this doesn't update the `range` that the `for` loop is working over.

Additionally, if you delete an element then increase the index, it's really as if you're increasing the index by 2, since everything gets shifted left by one index.

The best solution to this would be a list comprehension as Lattyware suggested.  Your for loop can be replaced with

```
L1 = [item for item in L1 if item not in L2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you care only about removing specific values from the list (and don't care about indexes, order etc.):

```
L1 = ['e', 'i', 'l', 'n', 's', 't']
L2 = ['e', 'i', 'l', 'n', 's', 't']

for item in L1:
    try:
        L2.remove(item)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

`print(L2)` gives: `[]`

Comment: -1.  This is grossly inefficient as it needs to shift all remaining items one space to the left each time an item is deleted.