# Stopwords Removal with Python

Tags: python, stop-words

I do not understand why this code does not work. When I click the run, it says "After stopwords removal: None".  Can anyone assist how to fix the problem ?  Many Thanks.

```
 stop_words = ["the", "of", "a", "to", "be", "from", "or"]
 last = lower_words.split()

 for i in stop_words:
     lastone = last.remove(i)
     print "\nAAfter stopwords removal:\n",lastone
```

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573115/delete-item-from-list-in-python-while-iterating-over-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`list.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) function modifies the list in place and returns `None`.

So when you do `last.remove(i)`, it will remove the first occurrence of `i` from the list `last` and return `None`, so `lastone` will always be set to `None`.

For what you are trying to do, you probably want all occurrences of an item from `stop_words` removed so `last.remove()` will not be the most efficient method.  Instead, I would do something like the following with a list comprehension:

```
stop_words = set(["the", "of", "a", "to", "be", "from", "or"])
last = lower_words.split()
last = [word for word in last if word not in stop_words]
```

Converting `stop_words` to a set is to make this more efficient, but you would get the same behavior if you left it as a list.

And for completeness, here is how you would need to do this with `remove()`:

```
stop_words = ["the", "of", "a", "to", "be", "from", "or"]
last = lower_words.split()
for word in stop_words:
    try:
        while True:
            last.remove(word)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: I have edited my answer with a suggestion of an alternative way to do this, if you still wanted to do with with `remove()` you could but you would need to put the `remove()` call within a loop inside of a try/except block to make sure all occurrences of each word are removed.

Comment: Many Thanks F.J.. It works properly now. But, now I need to cancel split function. How can I do that ? I mean I removed stopwords and want to print the list not as an array.

Comment: Use `' '.join(last)`, this will return a string with a space added between each element in `last`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that receives a text and returns the text without the stopword. It achieves its goal by ignoring every word in a dictionary stopwords. I use .lower() function for each word i because most of stopwords packages are on lowercase letter but our text may be not.

```
def cut_stop_words(text,stopwords):
  new_text= ''
  for i in text.split():

    if (i.lower()) in stopwords:
         pass
     else:
         new_text= new_text.strip() + ' ' + i

  return new_text
```