# Python list elements removal logical error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500888/removing-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)

I have this code:

```
s = [2,3,4,5]

for i in s:
  s.remove(i)

print(s)
```

When I run it, the result is:

```
[3,5]
```

What is the logical error here ?

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the list while modifying it, which is causing your problem.

Make a temporary list (`list(s)`) that you iterate over and modify the original to your needs:

```
>>> s = [2,3,4,5]
>>>
>>> for i in list(s):
...   s.remove(i)
... 
>>> print(s)
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The logical error is in removing elements from a list while iterating through the same list.

Python hides some implementation details, of course. Internally, you remove the first item, leaving `[3,4,5]`. Then you remove the second item, leaving `[3,5]`. At this point you have removed two items from a list that is only two items long, so you are done.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the iterator. Consider this code segment:

```
s = [2,3,4,5]

for i in s:
    print "i",i
    j = s
    print "j", j
    s.remove(i)
    print "removed"
    print "j", j
    print "s", s

print s
```

The output would be

```
i 2
j [2, 3, 4, 5]
removed
j [3, 4, 5]
s [3, 4, 5]
i 4
j [3, 4, 5]
removed
j [3, 5]
s [3, 5]
[3, 5]
```

Basically, when you execute the for loop, the the internal iterator goes to s[0], then s[1], etc. When the next round of the loop executes, s[1] is already 4 instead of 3 because s itself has been modified.