# Trying to produce a Random list of single digit integers which are not repeated. Getting only 5 instead of 9

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
from random import randint
SudList = []
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in numbers:
    SudList.append(numbers[randint(0,len(numbers)-1)])
    print("Sudlist-" + str(SudList))
    numbers.remove(SudList[-1])
    print("numbers-" + str(numbers))
print(SudList)
```

I expected this code to return something like this- (the final SudList)

```
[9,7,2,8,6,4,5,3,1]
```

But Instead it Returns something like this -

```
[9,4,6,7,2]
```

Here is the whole output-

```
Sudlist-[5]
numbers-[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Sudlist-[5, 1]
numbers-[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Sudlist-[5, 1, 9]
numbers-[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
Sudlist-[5, 1, 9, 3]
numbers-[2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
Sudlist-[5, 1, 9, 3, 4]
numbers-[2, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 1, 9, 3, 4]
Press any key to quit
```

How do i correct my code?

Comment: Well - you are removing elements from the list while iterating over it...? Any reason you can't use `random.shuffle` ?

Comment: I'd suggest you try `random.shuffle(numbers)`

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6500888/198633)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to stick with this piece of code, simply use `i in range len(numbers)` instead of `i in numbers`. Your remove statement is reducing the length of numbers and thus, the number of numbers printed is always `(len(numbers)+1)/2`

```
from random import randint
SudList = []
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    SudList.append(numbers[randint(0,len(numbers)-1)])
    print("Sudlist-" + str(SudList))
    numbers.remove(SudList[-1])
    print("numbers-" + str(numbers))
print(SudList)
```

Comment: That did it! thanks! Probably gonna use shuffle though

Comment: Yeah, sure! Happy I could help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`shuffle`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_shuffle.htm). It's will meet your needs.

```
import random
random.shuffle(numbers)
```

**output**

```
[7, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 6, 5, 9]
```

Comment: this is what i ended up using. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay with your implementation just change:

```
for i in numbers:
```

To:

```
for i in range(len(numbers)):
```

So you don't iterate over the list that changes

Comment: Wow, we thought of the same thing at nearly the same time!

Comment: How about `while numbers:` ? :)

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, shuffle is the quickest and most readable solution.

```
import random

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

However, it looks like you're wanting to see the state of each list at every step, so if you're looking for a custom implementation, you could also try the following:

```
from random import randint

Sudlist = []
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

while len(numbers) > 0:
    index = randint(0, len(numbers) - 1)
    Sudlist.append(numbers.pop(index))
    print('Sudlist-' + str(Sudlist))
    print('numbers-' + str(numbers))
print(Sudlist)
```