# Can anybody explain me why am i getting some erros with the following python code?

Tags: python, python-3.4

Can anybody explain me why am I getting some errors with the following python code?
The loop removes two tuple but one still in the list after the loop end.
The print at the end is not the result i am expected.

```
>>> liste=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(1,4),(3,4)]
>>> for couple in liste:
...    if int(1) in couple:
...        liste.remove(couple)
... 
>>> print(liste)
[(2, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You don't need to use `int(1)`; that's the same thing as `1`. The duplicate explains how to properly remove items from a list as you iterate. See [Loop "Forgets" to Remove Some Items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17299581) or [Removing from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500888) for posts that explain why your attempt doesn't work.

Comment: For future reference, you would need to include your *expected* output too, not just that the output you got was unexpected.

Comment: I read the posts you suggested, i think i understand now why i didn't get the expected output. Sorry i didn't explain well my problem. Thanks @Martijn Pieters

Answer (score -3):

After your for statement you should indent before starting the if statement.

> > > liste=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(1,4),(3,4)]
> > >       for couple in liste:

```
        if int(1) in couple:

            liste.remove(couple)
```

> > > print(liste)
> > >       [(2, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4)]

Comment: sorry but i updated my post. I am not familiar with the forum but the question was why my loop dont remove one tuple from the list.

Comment: It removes two tuple but one still in the list after the loop end.

Comment: Okay I didn't know that. Can you please remove the negative review of my answer?