# a recursion function that return an int

Tags: python, recursion

```
def nested_count(l : 'any nested list of int', a : int) -> int:
    c = 0
    while len(l) != 0:
        for x in l:
            if type(x) == int:
                if x == a:
                    c = c + 1
                    l.remove(x)
                    nested_count(l,a)
                else:
                    continue 
            elif type(x) == list:
                nested_count(x,a)
    return c
```

this function passed a nested list of ints and a single int as arguments; it returns the number of times the single int argument appears in the nested list argument, for example:

```
nested_count( [[1,2,[4,[1],8],[1,3,2]],[1,1]], 1 )
```

returns 5

I am not sure why my function does not work

can someone tell me how to fix it? many thanks.

Comment: You need to return the result of the recursive function call. For example `return nested_count(l,a)`

Comment: You shouldn't mutate the list while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding `nested_count` results to `c`:

```
def nested_count(lst, l):
    c = 0
    for i in lst:
        if i == l:
            c += 1
        elif type(i) == list:
            c += nested_count(i, l)
    return c
```

Also it is better to iterate over list with for.

Answer (score 1):

The results of the nested function calls are not used. You probably should replace the lines with `c += nested_count(l,a)` and `c += nested_count(x,a)`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mutate the list while iterate over it and you need to return the result from recursive calls. You could simplify function greatly by checking the type of `l` and if it's `int` then returning `bool` telling if it matches with `a`. In case `l` is a list just call `nested_count` recursively on its' items and `sum` the result:

```
def nested_count(l, a):
    # Base case
    if type(l) == int:
        return l == a
    return sum(nested_count(x, a) for x in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the heterogenous list? Why bother using typing if you're not going to type all the parameters? Why are you mutating the input?

```
from typing import List

def deep_count_elem (x:int, xs:List) -> int:
  # done
  if len(xs) == 0:
    return 0
  # if list, count in this list and recurse
  elif isinstance(xs[0], list):
    return deep_count_elem(x, xs[0]) + deep_count_elem(x, xs[1:])
  # if element matches, add 1
  elif x == xs[0]:
    return 1 + deep_count_elem(x, xs[1:])
  # otherwise add nothing, move to next element
  else:
    return deep_count_elem(x, xs[1:])

print(deep_count_elem(1, [[1,2,[4,[1],8],[1,3,2]],[1,1]])) # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you need to accumulate the return values from the recursive calls of `nested_count` to get the correct total.

Also, removing items from a list (or other collection) that you're iterating over can lead to unexpected results, see the SO Python Common Question [Removing items from a list while iterating over the list](http://sopython.com/canon/95/removing-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-the-list/) for details and a few relevant SO pages, in particular: [Removing from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500888/removing-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it).

It's generally preferred to [call `isinstance` rather than `type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) to do type testing. The `isinstance` function can test for multiple types in one call, it will also return True if the object is a subclass of the specified type.

Here are a couple of one-liners that handle lists or tuples.

```
def nested_count(l, a):
    return sum(nested_count(x, a) if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) else x == a for x in l)
```

and

```
def nested_count(l, a):
    return l.count(a) + sum(nested_count(x, a) for x in l if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)))
```