# How to use 'for x in list' if items are being removed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding a text adventure in python. I have a sheriff NPC that counts all `item` objects in `player.inventory`, and if `item.name == "dead goblin"` then the item is removed from the list, and `goblins_taken += 1`:

```
    if "sheriff" in player.action and "talk" in player.action and player.location == sheriff:
        goblins_taken = 0
        for item in player.inventory:
            if item.name == "dead goblin":
                goblins_taken += 1
                player.inventory.remove(item)
        write("The sheriff says, 'Good job. You have killed " + str(goblins_taken) + " goblins!")
```

The problem with this code was the fact that if the player killed 2 goblins, the sheriff would say that the player killed 1 goblin, not 2.

I tried to simplify the problem in IDLE and realized that it was an indexing problem:

```
>>> foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> foo[2]
'c' # With b
>>> foo.remove('b')
>>> foo[2]
'd' # Without b, index is shifted down
```

Is there some better method of removing items from a list than `list.remove()`? Or is there some way to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you simple give dead goblins a special tag (i.e. 'dead') and then count 'dead'?

Comment: Related reading: [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/953482), [Python: Removing list element while iterating over list \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022764/953482), [Removing from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500888/953482)

Comment: The simple way is to build a new list, but I also like John Machin's approach: do it backwards. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207485/4014959

Comment: I am not adding a `dead` tag to the goblins. Although I have considered it, I have other enemies based on the same `Enemy` class that the sheriff is not interested in which already have `if self.health <= 0` statements instead, so a `dead` tag would not be necessary. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never modify the list you are iterating through!
You could solve it by creating a second list:

```
temp_inventory = list(player.inventory)
for item in player.inventory:
    if item.name == "dead goblin":
        goblins_taken += 1
        temp_inventory.remove(item)
player.inventory = temp_inventory
```

This I have tried and works:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1]
b = list(a)
elems_removed = 0
for elem in a:
    if elem == 2:
        elems_removed += 1
        b.remove(elem)
print(a)
print(b)
a=b
print(a)
print(elems_removed)
```

Comment: @TemporalWolf: You are right. I have corrected my answer. Thanks for the warning. I had not tried the code for lack of runable code in the question.

Comment: You can make the temporary variable anonymous via: `for item in player.inventory[:]:` or `for item in list(player.inventory):` both of which make [shallow copies](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to iterate over.

Comment: That is what I changed in my answer.

Comment: Seemed pretty reasonable to me. Unfortunately, when I tested this out my Raspberry Pi completely stalled, so I had to unplug it. Turned it back on and going to see what happened.

Comment: There we go! I updated the code and it works. Thanks, mrCarnivore.

Comment: Probably better to iterate over the copy and remove from the original, just in case there are other references to the original. Or at the end of the loop do `player.inventory[:] = temp_inventory`. This technique is ok for small lists, but it's better to avoid `.remove` because it's slow: it has to do a linear scan of the whole list until it finds a matching item to remove, as mentioned in the linked question.