# For loop stops when removing an item in a seperate list - Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am learning Python and have been finding that for some reason my for loop will stop, even when there is more 'loops' to go.

This happens **ONLY** when I *delete an item from a list*. If the removal is commented out, it works: printing "RUNNING LISTING" twice and it will check 2 items against 2 in the list. If an item is deleted it will print once and will check only 1 item agaisnt the other 2. Both times the console has no error.

It stops with an independant list variable when the original isnt affected: `independant_list = looping_list`. and also stops with `list.remove(x)`, `list.pop(x)` and `del list[x]`.

currently the problem code is: `del listings_to_add[listing_count]`

Here is my code, in short (*I think*):

```
for A in ListX:
    for B in ListY:
        if A in ListY:
            ListX - remove(A)
```

And in Long:

```
listings_to_add = new_listing_list
    for listing_count, listing in enumerate(new_listing_list):
        found = False
        print('\nRUNNING LISTING\n')

        #Checks the listing against all in DB
        for count, i in enumerate(id_in_DB):
            if not found:

                # Checks links - cuts them to listingID
                if str(listing[4]).split('?rsqid')[0] == i[1].split('?rsqid')[0]:
                    same_link = True
                    del listings_to_add[listing_count]
                    found = True
                else:
                    print(f'Different link: "{listing[4]}" \nWith DB.......: "{i[1]}"')
```

I have read [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500888/removing-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) posts about why deleting from a list you are running through makes bugs, which is what I had done first, but it still stops after changes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"deleting from a list you are running through makes bugs"_: You are still doing it. `listings_to_add = new_listing_list` won't create a new list. Try `listings_to_add = new_listing_list[:]`.

Comment: I believe `list(new_listing_list)` would convey the intetin better than `new_listing_list[:]`

Comment: Btw, the short code makes no sense since you're not using `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are iterating `new_listing_list`, but `listings_to_add` is an alias, so when you `del listings_to_add[listing_count]`, you are affecting `new_listing_list`.

I decluttered your code. Try this:

```
listings_to_add = []
for listing_count, listing in enumerate(new_listing_list):
    for count, i in enumerate(id_in_DB):
        if str(listing[4]).split('?rsqid')[0] == i[1].split('?rsqid')[0]:
            same_link = True
            break
        listings_to_add.append(listing)
        print(f'Different link: "{listing[4]}" \nWith DB.......: "{i[1]}"')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **list comprehensions** to tackle this

```
for A in ListX:
    for B in ListY:
        if A in ListY:
            ListX - remove(A)
```

as

```
listX = [x for x in listX if x not in listY]
```