# How to update a list during a combination?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would like to compare the elements of a list, and at the end of each `for` loop the combination resumes with the new updated list.

```py
from itertools import combinations

aListe = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for first, second in combinations(aListe, 2):
    # do something
    aListe.remove(first)
```

```py
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

---

**more specific example of the *# do something***.

Imagine my list contains [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) polygon such as

```py
aListe = [polygon1, polygon2, polygon3, polygon4]
for first, second in combinations(aListe, 2):
    if area(first) > area(second):
        aListe.remove(first)
```

if the area of the first polygon in the list is already greater than the second I don't want it to be compared to the others. I would like the next `for` loop start on an updated list without the first polygon.

Comment: If you want to *compare* elements of a list, why do you *remove* something from the list?

Comment: Can you show what you expect to be the value of the list in each iteration?

Comment: Because depending on the result of each loop (in my #do something) I don't want to compare all the values between them.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I edited with an example.

Comment: In other words, you want to find the polygon in the list with the smallest area?

Comment: i feel like a cobination of vectorizing and builtins would work better for you

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, this is just an example. In my case I want to do a comparison on polygons with several #do something which can be complex, and at the end a polygon is deleted etc.. Thus it would be nice for me to just know  is it possible to simply update a list during an itertools.combinations() at each iteration ?

Comment: @Eumel Can you give me a small example?

Comment: make a list of areas and then use np.min(areas) (or np.argmin if you need the index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have seen, your code failed because `itertools.combinations` visits each list item multiple times and it can only be removed once (assuming that it is only contained once).

But even if you had added a check like `if first in aList` to circumvent this error, you might have gotten unexpected results, as is generally the case when removing items from a list while iterating over it, see [Removing from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500888/removing-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it).

In your case, instead of actually removing a polygon from the list, I would mark it as "removed" by adding it to a "removed" set, and skip an iteration if an already removed polygon is encountered again.

(Note, in order to add polygons to a set, if I understand https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html correctly, *"[…] use the geometry ids as keys since the shapely geometries themselves are not hashable."*)

```
from itertools import combinations

removed = set()
aListe = [polygon1, polygon2, polygon3, polygon4]
for first, second in combinations(aListe, 2):
    if id(first) in removed:
        continue
    if area(first) > area(second):
        removed.add(id(first))
```

Comment: +1, but a point to note: I totally agree that you shouldn't, but you *can* change the original list while iterating over the combinations as long as you make sure you don't try to remove the same element twice (which causes the `ValueError` the OP faced).