# Python code throws error list out of range, even though the logic is same

Tags: python, list

**1)**

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        i = 1
        while i < len(nums)-1:
            if nums[i]==nums[i-1] and nums[i]==nums[i+1]:
                del nums[i]
            else:
                i+=1
        return len(nums)
```

The code above happens to work perfectly.

**2)**

```
class Solution:
        def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
            n = len(nums)-1
            i = 1
            while i < n:
                if nums[i]==nums[i-1] and nums[i]==nums[i+1]:
                    del nums[i]
                else:
                    i+=1
            return len(nums)
```

But the 2nd code throws this error :-

```
IndexError: list index out of range
    if nums[i]==nums[i-1] and nums[i]==nums[i+1]:
```

The logic behind both the codes happens to be same, in the first code we don't store the length of the list `nums`, instead we use it in while loop directly like `while < len(nums) - 1`

In the second code, we store the value of len(nums) in a variable `n`, and use it in a similar fashion in the while loop, `while i < n - 1`

I don't understand what's the difference between the two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500888/removing-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two snippets are *not* identical.

Notice that the list is modified inside the loop with `del nums[i]`, so its length changes.

In the first code, you access `len(nums)` every time you need it, so you always get the correct value of `len(nums)`.

In the second code, when you do `n = len(nums) - 1`, the value of `len(nums) - 1` at that time is assigned to the variable `n`. This variable isn't automatically updated when the value of `len(nums)` changes, so even after you delete elements of the list, `n` still has its original value.